# Physic nature of a real lightsaber

Tags: weapons

Every time I think about the construction of a lightsaber, I face all the reasons that a construction of one would be impossible (plasma, laser, lack of contact of light, etc.). So I started thinking, even going against knowledge based canon, that if a lightsaber was built as a micro-shield generator that emitted a thin length-specific shield, most of the problems related to no contact of light against light (or plasma), energy consumption (not very small but much smaller) and most of all parry and energy bolts deflection would be solved! Anyone with more physics knowledge think this is possible, or am I wrong?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/scientifically-plausible-lightsaber) for inspiration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the canonical operation of the shields in Star Wars, would you mind explaining how those are supposed to work?

Comment: The canonical knowledge, was about the lightsaber being a laser or plasma emmiter, sorry if i was not clear(english is not my main language),2012rchanpion, thanks for the observation, is there a way to move my question, or correlate it with that question you mentioned?It really is relevant, as i see.

Comment: I find it funny that on one hand they have lightsabers, which imply very advanced shield knowledge, but on the other hand ships do not have force fields.

Comment: AFAIK - and I'm not a SW expert - the blade of a lightsaber is turbulent plasma which is contained in some sort of a force field. It follows a string of a double helix out until it reaches the end of the blade, then turns back and returns to the handle on the other half helix. Early lightsabers were "single-helix" and really resource-consuming, so they were linked to a wrist-mounted battery by a cable.